# Adding custom engine in OpenSSL returns an error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openssl

I have installed OpenSSL 1.1.1d and added the following library `gost.so` under `/opt/openssl-1.1.1d/lib/engines-1.1/`

I also modified the `openssl.cnf` file located at `/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf` as follows:

```
openssl_conf = openssl_def

[openssl_def] 
engines = engine_section 
 
[engine_section] 
gost = gost_section 
 
[gost_section] 
engine_id = gost 
dynamic_path = /opt/openssl-1.1.1d/lib/engines-1.1/gost.so
default_algorithms = ALL 
CRYPT_PARAMS = id-Gost28147-89-CryptoPro-A-ParamSet
```

However, when I try `/opt/openssl-1.1.1d/bin/openssl engine` I get the following error:

```
(dynamic) Dynamic engine loading support
281473248541120:error:25066067:DSO support routines:dlfcn_load:could not load the shared library:crypto/dso/dso_dlfcn.c:118:filename(/opt/openssl-1.1.1d/lib/engines-1.1/gost.so): /opt/openssl-1.1.1d/lib/engines-1.1/gost.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
281473248541120:error:25070067:DSO support routines:DSO_load:could not load the shared library:crypto/dso/dso_lib.c:162:
281473248541120:error:260B6084:engine routines:dynamic_load:dso not found:crypto/engine/eng_dyn.c:414:
281473248541120:error:260BC066:engine routines:int_engine_configure:engine configuration error:crypto/engine/eng_cnf.c:140:section=gost_section, name=dynamic_path, value=/opt/openssl-1.1.1d/lib/engines-1.1/gost.so
281473248541120:error:0E07606D:configuration file routines:module_run:module initialization error:crypto/conf/conf_mod.c:177:module=engines, value=engine_section, retcode=-
```

The error above is so confusing because it states as if the file doesn't exist but it's inside the directory 100%.

Is there a way to fix it?